# Child sites are slowly loading images from main site (main site is super fast)

Tags: multisite, optimization, cloudflare

We have an un-solved (and very large) speed issue with this site: https://micronordic.com/dk/ and all other 26 child sites on the http://micronordic.com/ domain.

The child sites are loading the images from the main site https://micronordic.com/ but by doing this it slows down the image loading very much on the child sites.

So, if you go to http://micronordic.com (the main site) and you browse around you will experience that it is very quickly loading the images (and all else) whereas if you go to the footer and jump to the child sites (translated sites) you will see that their image loading is very slow (compared the very quickly loading on the main site).

It is surely because each site has their own htaccess file so when a child site is loading an image on the main site 2 htaccess files need to be run. In this, we are basically asking to load the images like it was from a different domain (even though we see it as the same domain), hence the delay.

We cannot copy out all the images so each child site has its own set of (identical) images as this will increase the number of images extremely much and the administration gets too complex as well.

After having tech crises with clients, we have always ended up with a good solution at CloudFlare at some point. The domain + DNS is hosted at CloudFlare.

If there is no site nor webserver solution to the challenge, perhaps a CloudFlare solution can be found?

Thank you for your time and advice :-)

UPDATE: We had 2-3 image 301-redirects on each child site which was the issue. We have fixed it now for the UK site and will fix the rest of the child sites soon.

Comment: the images actually load very fast, that's not the problem, and you're assuming those images are present and available on the page immediately, but I don't think that's the case at all. It's not that the images start loading immediately but take a second to load, it's that the timage don't exist until a second later. Look at the network tab and you'll see the actual requests to fetch the images are very quick. Also after refreshing the page the FR site loads as fast as the original

Comment: there's also something called Litespeed in the browser console that's lazy loading things, this is probably nothing to do with DNS, Cloudflare, or your images being loaded on a child site, those are all coincidental.